# Is there a way to use ONE procedure for multiple buttons in Pascal?

Tags: variables, event-handling, pascal, lazarus, procedures

I am looking for a way to use one procedure for multiple buttons. It's for a quiz like you have to press Button 1 for question 1, but copy and pasting the whole code for 36 buttons and changing the variables for 36 buttons isn't really fun for anybody.

So I thought something like this would be possible:

```
procedure TForm1.Button[x]Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoTask[x];
end;
```

X being the variable.

Is something like that possible or are there other ways to acquire the same result?

Comment: Retrieve "x" from tbutton(sender).name instead ? Just scan backwards for numeric digits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is:

1. Number the buttons using the `Tag` property in the Object Inspector (or in code when they're created) in order to easily tell them apart. (Or assign the value you want to be passed to your procedure/function when that button is clicked.)
2. Create one event handler, and assign it to all of the buttons you want to be handled by the same code.
3. The `Sender` parameter the event receives will be the button that was clicked, which you can then cast as a `TButton`.

   ```
   procedure TForm1.ButtonsClick(Sender: TObject);
   var
     TheButton: TButton;
   begin
     TheButton := Sender as TButton;
     DoTask(TheButton.Tag);
   end;
   ```

Comment: Well, thank you kindly sir for the help. However I am fairly if not really inexperienced with Pascal so...Could elaborate on step 2 if you would be so kind? Like I don't really know how to use Event Handler let alone create one from scratch even if it's a basic one.

Comment: Double-click on any one of the buttons in the IDE, which will create the shell of the routine (for instance, `Button1Click`). Use the Events tab for that button in the Object Inspector to rename it to something more generic (such as `ButtonsClick`). Ctrl-click all of the buttons on the form that you want to share the same event, switch to the Object Inspector Events tab, and select that generic `ButtonsClick` event as the OnClick handler for all the buttons. (Or simply assign it to each of them separately using the Object Inspector.)

Comment: Well thanks that makes it much clearer! But one more quick question is how can I assign the Tbutton.tag to a variable?    QuestionNumber:= TButton.Tag; won't work for obvious reason

Comment: `QuestionNumber := (Sender as TButton).Tag` works, as does `TButton(Sender).Tag` (as long as you're sure `Sender` is a `TButton`).